# AndroidPlot custom variable vertex color

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I would like to plot my values with the vertex point color dependent on the value. Ex, value of 10 generates a red point on the graph, 20 does green, etc.

I imagine this could be done with a custom pointandlabelformatter, but the only methods of interest there was setVertexPaint. I dont want to set the paint for the whole thing, that wouldnt help. I need to find where the actual vertex is drawn, and override that method, but i cant seem to find where it is.

Comment: There is nothing to do that in library .May be u have to edit lib.

Comment: Ya, i figured i wasnt going to be able to get it the way i wanted. I ended up just removing the graph in my app, the library is more trouble than its worth.